# Subscript notation logic check

Tags: vectors, kronecker-product, kronecker-symbol

Given 
$$\nabla\cdot(\textbf{r}\times\nabla f)~=~(\nabla\times\textbf{r})\cdot\nabla f~-~\textbf{r}\cdot(\nabla\times\nabla f)$$

I would split the equation into 2 part:

$(1)~~~~~~~~~(\nabla\times\textbf{r})\cdot\nabla f = [\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_j}]\partial_if=0\cdot\partial_if = 0$

$(2)~~~~~~~~~\textbf{r}\cdot(\nabla\times\nabla f)=x_i~\epsilon_{ijk}~\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}~\partial_k~f=(-\epsilon_{kji}\delta_{ji})~\partial_k~f = 0 \cdot \partial_k~f =0$

Therefore $\nabla\cdot(\textbf{r}\times\nabla f)~=~0$.

Here are the questions:

(1) Is it alright if I split it into half

(2) I would like to know the comments on using the notation

Comment: $(1)$ Yes.  $(2)$ You did the first term correctly but for the second one $x_i\partial_j \ne \delta_{ij}$.  The actual reason the second term is zero is because the curl of the gradient is zero which you can show using [Clairaut's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).

Comment: thanks for answering, however I have used $\frac{\partial~x_i}{\partial~x_j}~=~\delta_{ji}$

Comment: Where did you get $\frac{\partial~x_i}{\partial~x_j}$ in the second term?  The $x_i$ is not being differentiated.

Comment: I see, isnt it possible swap $x_i~\epsilon_{ijk}~\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}~\partial_k~f$ into $\epsilon_{ijk}~\frac{\partial x_i~}{\partial x_j}~\partial_k~f$ ???

Comment: You can move scalars around all you like but the only function being differentiated in the second term is the $f$.  So no -- you can't do that.

Comment: so the only solution to the second term is Clairaut's theorem? jus wondering if i can use subscript notation..

Comment: You can certainly write out the proof using subscript notation, you'll just have to make use of Clairaut's theorem somewhere.  Try to prove for yourself (using subscript notation if you like) that $\nabla \times \nabla f=0$.  If you get stuck let me know and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: I got $\epsilon_{ijk}~\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}f$, then I used the Claircut's theorem to show $\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}~=~\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}$ and exchange the dummy subscript i and j. We know that $\epsilon{jik}~=~-~\epsilon{ijk}$, so the only possibility of sth equals to its negative value is zero.

Comment: Yep.  That's how you do it.  Good job.

Comment: I appreciate you very much :)